# Changing text of the ticks in the axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis-labels

I am creating a bar chart, and I would like to change the text of my ticks. In the dataset, I had as a head of column one word (for example, food), but I would like to display as a text "Food, drinks and tobacco".

I have tried to do something like this, but it is not working:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
.tickFormat(function(d) { if (text=== "food"){
   return "Food, drinks and tobacco"
     }; })
```

I could not set that title in the CSV because if the name of the column has gaps in the middle if its words, D3 cannot read them.

Comment: You need an `else` also or will get `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here. First, the parameter you're using is `d`, not `text`. Second, without the `else`, you're not returning the other ticks properly.

So, it should be:

```
if (d === "Food") {
  return "Food, drinks and tobacco"
} else {
  return d
};
```

Or even simpler, with a ternary operator:

```
return d === "Food" ? "Food, drinks and tobacco" : d;
```

Here is a basic demo (using the y axis for better readability):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .range([20, 130])
  .domain(["Food", "Clothing", "Transportation", "Health"]);
var axis = d3.axisLeft(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d === "Food" ? "Food, drinks and tobacco" : d;
  })
var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150,0)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Regarding your last paragraph:

> I could not set that title in the CSV because if the name of the column has gaps in the middle if its words, D3 cannot read them.

That's not correct, and that has nothing to do with D3. This is a JavaScript issue: for property names with spaces, just use bracket notation:

```js
var someObject = {
  "a property name with spaces": 42
};

console.log(someObject["a property name with spaces"])
```